# Hibernate - Override output format of date when generating JSON

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

With a temporal in my entity defined like:

```
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "start_time", length = 19, nullable = false)
  public Date getStartTime() {
    return this.startTime;
  }

  public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
  }
```

And marshaling JSON out put like this (simplified):

```
  @GET
  @RestSecure
  @Path("/list")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response list(){
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(myEntityList).build();
  }
```

Is there a simple way of overriding output date format?

What I am getting out is the epoch like this:

```
"startTime": 1582261711000,
```

What I need is the date in ISO 8601 format like this:

```
"startTime": "2020-02-21T05:08:31Z",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jackson's `DateFormat` annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Comment: Outstanding, I knew there must be an easy way to do this.  Thank you!!!